# Magento checkout button not working

Tags: magento

I am trying add to add my own theme to magento 1.9. Almost implemented but encountered a problem. When I clicked the proceed to checkout button from the cart page the it redirects to a page showing the checkout steps. There is no area to enter the shipping address, nothing. Then no buttons are there to proceed further. Please help me from this problem.

Comment: Check in console for any JavaScript error are displaying.

Comment: Have you merged JS files?

Comment: Have you overridden all the files from base/default theme ?